# unrecognised rule in lex

Tags: unix, lex

I am new to lex and i have an unrecognised rule on line 36 which is - printf("%d", tok);
I am unsure on how to fix this error.. does anyone see how to fix this?
Thankyou

```
%{
enum yytokentype {
NUMBER = 258,
ADD = 259,
SUB = 260,
MUL = 261,
DIV = 262,
ABS = 263,
EOL = 264
};
int yylval;
%}

%%
"+"
{ return ADD; }
"-"
{ return SUB; }
"*"
{ return MUL; }
"/"
{ return DIV; }
"|"
{ return ABS; }
[0-9]+ { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
\n
{ return EOL; }
. { printf("Mystery character %c\n", *yytext); }
[ \t] { }
%%
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int tok;

while(tok = yylex()) {
printf("%d", tok);
if(tok == NUMBER) printf(" = %d\n", yylval);
else printf("\n");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong here, but I'll talk you through my thought process.

Firstly, the error suggests that it *thinks* that your `main` block is a lex rule. Clearly it isn't. This suggests that it doesn't think that your rules have ended.

I see a couple of weird things in your rules. You have a "blank" rule at the end, after the `.` wildcard. That rule will never get matched. It should be harmless but you might want to make sure why you're including it.

Next, you have your patterns and your code on different lines. I don't think that's valid. Try putting the code on the same line at the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Your code corrected (spot the differences):

```
%option noyywrap
%{
enum yytokentype {
    NUMBER = 258,
    ADD = 259,
    SUB = 260,
    MUL = 261,
    DIV = 262,
    ABS = 263,
    EOL = 264 
};
int yylval;
%}

%%
"+" { return ADD; }
"-" { return SUB; }
"*" { return MUL; }
"/" { return DIV; }
"|" { return ABS; }
[0-9]+ { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
\n { return EOL; }
[ \t] { } 
. { printf("Mystery character %c\n", *yytext); }
%%

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int tok;

while(tok = yylex()) {
printf("%d", tok);
if(tok == NUMBER) printf(" = %d\n", yylval);
else printf("\n");
}
```